# Geckodriver unexpectedly exits when running multiple Firefox instances through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am developing a system that runs 100+ headless Firefox instances through python Selenium.

The number of live instances are launched gradually, 10-20 at a time, until the entire system is operational.

This happens without problem for the first 50-60 instances. At any time above that new instances start to fail, seemingly randomly with the following error message being returned by selenium:

```
Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0
```

I'm using `selenium v3.8.1`, `Firefox 57.0.1`, `geckodriver 0.19.1`. This is all running on a `Ubuntu` instance on `AWS`.

So far I've tried searching both `selenium`-, and `Firefox` forums without much luck. The error message or the status code from `selenium` has lead me nowhere.

Here's the full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[..]/utils.py", line 283, in launch_browser
    client = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, log_path=log_path)
  File "[..]/.virtualenvs/user/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 148, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "[..]/.virtualenvs/user/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "[..]/.virtualenvs/user/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0
```

I have also looked into the my `geckodriver` logs. They are quite verbose so I'm not sure which lines are relevant to the above problem. One that strikes me as a possible trouble spot is the following:

```
1518573330504   addons.xpi-utils    WARN    addMetadata: Add-on activity-stream@mozilla.org is invalid: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520006 (NS_ERROR_FILE_TARGET_DOES_NOT_EXIST) [nsIFile.isFile]"  nsresult: "0x80520006 (NS_ERROR_FILE_TARGET_DOES_NOT_EXIST)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIInstall.jsm :: this.loadManifestFromFile :: line 971"  data: no] Stack trace: this.loadManifestFromFile()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIInstall.jsm:971 < syncLoadManifestFromFile()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:947 < addMetadata()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProviderUtils.js:1231 < processFileChanges()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProviderUtils.js:1578 < checkForChanges()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:3265 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:2182 < callProvider()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:263 < _startProvider()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:730 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:897 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:3081 < observe()@jar:file:///opt/firefox/omni.ja!/components/addonManager.js:65
```

EDIT:
I just notced this in the sys logs:

`[774967.585584] firefox[66283]: segfault at 0 ip 0000000000409509 sp 00007ffffd908800 error 6 in firefox[400000+2c000]`

EDIT 2:
Here are some further details on the server specs.

It's an `m4.16xlarge` Amazon EC2 instance type. It's promised specs are therefore 64 vCPUs with 256 GiB of RAM.

Comment: Error seems to be in the line `client = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, log_path=log_path)`. Can you update the question with your code trial and geckodriver error stack trace?

Comment: This link may be helpful: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/370 -- particularly the following: "The xvfb-run command used to run the 'headless' browser instances can only support 256 max 'clients' for it's 'screen'. After starting ~64 chrome instances (every chrome seems to consume 2 'clients'), this limit is reached and no new ones can be started. For Firefox, this is ~46 instances (it seems that Firefox consumes 3 'clients')."